# What is the one dimensional image that the torus with one circular hole on its surface homeomorphic to?

Tags: general-topology

I am really poor of geometry imagination and struggled to figure this out.

Comment: A torus, with or without a hole, is two-dimensional, and thus not homeomorphic to any one-dimensional image.

Comment: So, would you like to clarify? Is Eric's answer what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I want

Comment: In that case, let me encourage you to "accept" Eric's answer by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: You could do that today, Doug.

Comment: sorry I though you mean the upvote button as I did not notice that small check button below, my apology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.math.wisc.edu/~ccheng/courses/Hatcher.pdf

The deformation retract of a once punctured torus is a bouquet (i.e., wedge product) of two circles.